Firebase Crashlytics asking for non-existent dSYM files
I have a .NET 8 MAUI iOS app on testflight and am having trouble with symbolicated crash logs. I migrated from Xamarin which was working find with Crashlytics, but now I can see there's crashes under a non-existent UUID when I look in the dSYMs tab. Even when I upload both the dSYMs found in the .xcarchive in Xcode and bin/release of my project in Visual Studio they are uploaded but marked as Unknown.
I have run the mdfind -name .dSYM | while read -r line; do dwarfdump -u "$line"; done command on my Mac which generates a list of all the dSYM UUIDs and none of which match the one Firebase is looking for.
A slightly related problem is that (even with Xamarin) on App Store Connect in the build metadata, I can see it says symbols are included but there's no option to download them. I also get an error when I select "Download Debug Symbols" on Xcode that says "No dSYMs were found for Version x.x.x."
I am using version 8.10.0.3 of Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Analytics/CloudMessaging/Crashlytics and Xcode 15.4.
Here are the ones that have been uploaded but have no events:

Here are the ones Firebase is expecting that have events tied to them:

